# Empty response is returned when endpoint is called with code, but correct response is returned when called with Postman

Tags: python, api, postman, python-asyncio

```
import asyncio
import time
import aiohttp

async def player(name, n, session):
    print(f'number-{n}')
    url = f'https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/element-summary/{n}/'
    response = await session.request(method='GET', url=url)
    value = await response.text()
    return value

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        response = await player('armaan', 233, session)
        print("response: ",response)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.perf_counter()
    asyncio.run(main())
    elapsed = time.perf_counter() - start
    print(elapsed)
```

when I call the URL using code then empty response is returned, but when I call the endpoint using Postman correct response is returned.
FYI - Just started learning python and asyncio. I will be highly obliged if someone could help me with this.

**response:**

```
<ClientResponse(https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/) [200 OK]>
<CIMultiDictProxy('Connection': 'close', 'Content-Length': '0', 'Server': 'Varnish', 'Retry-After': '0', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 'Date': 'Thu, 28 Oct 2021 16:14:11 GMT', 'Via': '1.1 varnish', 'X-Served-By': 'cache-dfw18667-DFW', 'X-Cache': 'MISS', 'X-Cache-Hits': '0', 'X-Timer': 'S1635437652.864164,VS0,VE0')>
```

Comment: Maybe see what else (apart from `text`) is in the response - there may be clues there.

Comment: @doctorlove the content length returned via the code is empty.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Asyncio: GET call is returning empty response on FPL API endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69758559/python-asyncio-get-call-is-returning-empty-response-on-fpl-api-endpoint)